# Failure to store data using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, nested-if

I'm trying to do a small cashier program in Excel VBA. However, I'm stuck in the part where I would like to add an additional orders. On my form, I have 4 combo boxes. Drinks, Sides, Specialties, and Individuals. What I would like to achieve is to add whatever value the combo boxes have to my listbox within the form, and also add them to the sheet I have ("TABLE 1") when I click on add button. If there's no value, it will ignore that combo box and check the next.

Here are my codes:

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()

Range("A2").Select

If MsgBox("ADD ORDERS?", vbYesNo, "CONFIRMATION") = vbYes Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow
Set ws = Sheets("TABLE 1")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Overview")
ws.Unprotect "321321"
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add

lr.Range(1, 1).Value = Date

If cmbdrinks.Value = "SMB BUCKET" Then
lr.Range(1, 2).Value = cmbdrinks.Value
ListBox1.AddItem (cmbdrinks.Value)
txtbill.Value = txtbill.Value + 258
lr.Range(1, 3).Value = 258
lr.Range(1, 4).Value = Time
lr.Range(1, 4).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = ws1.Range("I4").Value

ElseIf cmbdrinks.Value = "SMB TOWER" Then
lr.Range(1, 2).Value = cmbdrinks.Value
ListBox1.AddItem (cmbdrinks.Value)
txtbill.Value = txtbill.Value + 288
lr.Range(1, 3).Value = 288
lr.Range(1, 4).Value = Time
lr.Range(1, 4).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = ws1.Range("I4").Value

If cmbside.Value = "NACHOS" Then
    lr.Range(1, 2).Value = cmbside.Value
    ListBox1.AddItem (cmbside.Value)
    txtbill.Value = txtbill.Value + 58
    lr.Range(1, 3).Value = 58
    lr.Range(1, 4).Value = Time
    lr.Range(1, 4).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    lr.Range(1, 5).Value = ws1.Range("I4").Value

ElseIf cmbside.Value = "FRENCH FRIES" Then
    lr.Range(1, 2).Value = cmbside.Value
    ListBox1.AddItem (cmbside.Value)
    txtbill.Value = txtbill.Value + 48
    lr.Range(1, 3).Value = 48
    lr.Range(1, 4).Value = Time
    lr.Range(1, 4).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    lr.Range(1, 5).Value = ws1.Range("I4").Value

Else
End If


Else
End If
```

Assuming that I've selected the values "SMB BUCKET" and "NACHOS", What's happening is that when I click on the "CMDADD" button, it stores the data in my listbox with no problem, SMB BUCKET and NACHOS are listed, the price showing in "TXTBILL" is correct as well. However, the data stored on my sheet "TABLE 1" only contains the last item that I've added, in this instance, the "NACHOS", even though I've selected the "SMB BUCKET" on my first combo box.

I think I'm nesting my statements incorrectly, or do I need to use loop statements? I hope someone can guide me through this small project of mine. If there's an easy way to achieve what I want I would highly appreciate the help!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you’ve created only one row to store your results in.  You are overwriting the value each time.  You need a new list row for each item.

Under your `ElseIf cmbdrinks.Value = "SMB TOWER" Then` statement add the following two lines:

```
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add
lr.Range(1, 1).Value = Date
```

This will add a row for the Nachos or fries.

Also, if you don’t have anything for the `Else` block, then you don’t need to include it.

Your `If…Then` statements can be as follows:

```
If <test condition> Then
ElseIf <test condition> Then
End If
```